# Prime numbers with binomial coefficients

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $n$ a positive integer. Prove that $p+1$ divides $n$ if and only if $$\sum_{k\equiv j\pmod{p-1}}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{\frac{(k-j)}{p-1}}\equiv 0 \mod p$$
for every $$j\in \left \{ 1,3,5,\ldots,p-2 \right \}$$

Comment: Where is $n$ in that sum?

Comment: Please clarify the set that $j$ is drawn from I don't understand the pattern.

Comment: Fixed. I have been trying to do this question for almost 12 hours but I don't seem to be doing any useful progress.

Comment: If $n=21,j=1,p=5,$ then $4p+1=n$,however,
$$\sum_{k\equiv j\pmod{p-1}}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{\frac{(k-j)}{p-1}}
\equiv  \binom{21}{1}-\binom{21}{5}+\binom{21}{9}-\binom{21}{13}+\binom{21}{17}-\binom{21}{21}$$
$$\equiv 21-20349+293930-203490+5985-1 \equiv 1-9+0-0+5-1\equiv 1 ≠0 \mod 5$$
Please tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Still some problems,if $n=16,p=7,j=4$, then the left hand of the equation $\equiv 1 \pmod p$.I think $j$ is always odd,so $$j\in \left \{ 1,3,5,7,\ldots,p-2 \right \}$$